# How to setup a fake ntp server?

Tags: networking, ntp

How can I setup a local ntp server with "fake" time? 
For testing purposes, any machine B that I configure to have A as ntp server should receive times at an offset to true time (e.g., one week in the past or one month in the future) that can be configured at A.
I suppose this could be done like this [Setting up a standalone NTP server on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488072/setting-up-a-standalone-ntp-server-on-ubuntu)
, but I'd prefer that the server A itself remains at correct system time (e.g., by itself sync'ing to faithful ntp servers).

Comment: I believe you can set up a standalone NTP server that gets its time from a reference network NTP server, but adds or subtracts an offset by use of the `fudge` command. See e.g. [here](http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.0/clockopt.htm).