# How to find time difference between two computers?

Tags: 16.04, server, time, ntp

I'm running a distributed computer setup with one machine as time server for the other so the two are in sync to the accuracy of a few ms.

I followed answers on this question:
[How do I setup a local NTP server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14558/how-do-i-setup-a-local-ntp-server)

I was able to setup successfully, but I want to know if there is a way to query ntp or any other program and know the time difference between the two machines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `ntpq -np` will output information about time difference between your NTP server and the sources it is synchronizing to (I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want). If you omit `-n` parametr (ie. `ntpq -p`) it will display hostnames instead of IP addresses (slightly slower, as it has to do DNS lookups).

The command `ntpdate -q <address>` will output information about time difference between your machine and the time source specified in `<address>`. The `-q` parametr is important, as without it `ntpdate` will try to sync time to the specified machine instead of just outputting the difference. It is possible that you need to type full path to `ntpdate` (eg. `/usr/sbin/ntpdate`) if running from non-root user.

(`ntpq` should be installed with ntp package, `ntpdate` is a separate package so you have to install it if it's not already installed)

Comment: Hey raj, thanks for your answer, I received following output:
server 10.42.0.199, stratum 16, offset 143905128.738459, delay 0.07806
11 Feb 22:13:36 ntpdate[1501]: no server suitable for synchronization found

The offset seems correct, but why does it complain no server suitable for synchronization found?
Thanks!

Comment: stratum 16 means that machine 10.42.0.199 is not synchronized to any time source - therefore "no servers suitable for synchronization", because NTP protocol refuses to synchronize time to a source that is not synchronized itself.

Comment: True, when I connected the server to the internet, the client stopped complaining and it shows stratum 2. I'd like to read more about NTP, could you share a link which has all the information about it?

Comment: Well... I'm not sure about the link, I learned most things just by working with NTP... but maybe you could start with the NTP FAQ: http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/