# Isolated NTP Server for use in switchgear testing

Tags: server, sync, ntp

I need to set up an NTP server to test the NTP functionality of some power meters (PXM2000), gateways (PXG900), and MOXAS in a switchgear application.  For my application I do not care about precise time as I am working without an internet connection, and I am hoping that I can just use the local time on the computer.  I simply want to see the time change and sync on all the devices that use NTP for time synchronization as it is my job to confirm the communication of all devices.

This is my first attempt at setting up a server and I am hoping that someone can fill in the gaps as to where I have gone wrong.  I have been trying to make this happen using a Rpi 4, a computer running ubuntu 20.04, and I have also tried using a windows machine.

For the Linux based machines I have followed the steps provided in the highest rated answer shown in:
[How do I setup a local NTP server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14558/how-do-i-setup-a-local-ntp-server)

As this didn't quite work straight across for the Rpi I have also gone both directions as a server and client via both machines following the steps provided here:
https://medium.com/@rishabhdevyadav/how-to-install-ntp-server-and-client-s-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-f0562e41d0e1

The windows machine I simply followed: http://techtips.tv/windows/configure-ntp-server-on-windows-10-client-or-windows-server-2019/

clearly there is more todo than this as it didn't work when the devices in the switchgear were directed towards the computers IP address.

Without internet access I have yet to see the Linux NTP server say it is synchronized on the server or client side.

I will be starting again with fresh installs on both Linux machines, and I am wondering if what I am trying to accomplish is possible or if it does not work the way I am trying to run it. If not, what is the easiest way to set this up because everything I have read sounds simple, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

the howto you followed is high ranked, but also a decade old. Nowadays I'd recommend to use `chrony` as outlined in the [ubuntu server guide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-ntp).
This essentially comes down to just

```
$ apt install chrony
$ vim /etc/chrony/chrony.conf
# set from which networks/addresses NTP can be synced
$ sudo systemctl restart chrony.service
```

Since you don't care about the accuracy of the time I think that should be all you need. I use it on my RPi4 (with network and a GPS receiver for extra accuracy) just fine.

> Note/Warning: Many NTP clients do a quality check on the time source
> they fetch from for jitter, distance and such. If your server has
> nothing but it's local clock and it might be really bad they might
> *disqualify* it and therefore not sync. If you happen to use `chrony` as a client on one of your test clients check `chronyc sources` and
> `chronyc sourcestats`

Comment: Thank you!  I will give this a go today.

Comment: Wow. with all the failures I had trying to get the outdated version to work. Chrony was straightforward and easy.  Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help, in that case please upvote the answer so that it is more obvious for other people coming by here.